# Multi model search in sunspot rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

My model is

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :category_products
has_many :categories , through: :category_products
has_many :product_tags
has_many :tags, through: :product_tags
```

I want to search all three models Category,Tags,Products.It works fine but issue I face is that when I search Category and Tag I want to get there related products.But how I differentiate when search only product column and when its associated tables.

My code is

```
@search = Sunspot.search[Product,Category,Tag] do
    fulltext params[:search]
    paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 3)
  end
  @products = @search.results
```

At the end I want to get products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add '*categories*' and '*tags*' into your product search information like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :name
    text :categories do
      categories.map { |category| category.name }
    end
    text :tags do
      tags.map { |tag| tag.name }
    end
  end
end

@search = Sunspot.search(Product) do
  fulltext params[:search]
  paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 3)
end
@products = @search.results
```

link: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot

Hope this help!